Adapting a charging circuit from NiMh to use Na-Ion batteries. What should I look out for?
Following on from a past question about Sodium-Ion charge controllers, I've recently finished a redesign of a BMS circuit. As I see that Sodium-Ion batteries are the next battery type that has characteristics very similar to NiMh (doesn't catch fire/emit a significant amount of heat, low discharge compared to Lithium-based batteries), I figured I'd easily be able to replace the batteries in my circuit accordingly, with only adjustments to the charging voltage.
Is this the case, or are there other apartments that should realistically be made in order to adapt an NiMh battery charge controller-BMS to be a Na-Ion controller-BMS?
For those curious about my schematic so far:


I'm specifically looking at these Na-ion batteries, rated at 3V, and that have 1.5Ah, for those interested in which battery i'm looking at, as a rough guide.

So what was the charging curve the charger was designed for and what is the charging curve for the new battery technology? Constant current? constant voltage? float voltage?

From the question/answer you linked it seems pretty clear that you should be modifying a Li-ion charger, not a NiMH charger.

@Finbarr I went through a long process of determining which battery chemistry to use before settling on NiMH, then moving to Na-ion.
